# MySQL row with table name

Tags: mysql

I want to ask how to show table name along your data. For example I have 2 tables.

TV SHOWS

```
id            (int)
title         (varchar)
release_date  (date)
```

Movies

```
id            (int)
title         (varchar)
release_date  (date)
```

I would like to display

```
id  title  release_date  table_name
```

So the question is how to display table name data is taken from.

Comment: select 'MOVIES' as table_name from MOVIES

Comment: what output you are expecting? one table with data from both table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply try:

```
SELECT id, title, release_date, 'TV shows' as table_name
FROM `TV shows`
UNION ALL
SELECT id, title, release_date, 'Movies' as table_name
FROM `Movies`
```

Comment: Thank that's what I wanted :)